# How to create a conditional incremented column in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I'd like to create a conditional incremented column in polars.
It should start from 1 and increment only if a certain condition (pl.col('code') == 'L') is met.

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'file': ['a.txt','a.txt','a.txt','a.txt','b.txt','b.txt','c.txt','c.txt','c.txt','c.txt','c.txt'],
                   'code': ['X','Y','Z','L','A','A','B','L','C','L','X']
                   })
df.with_columns(pl.int_range(start=1, end=pl.len()+1).over('file').alias('rrr')
                )
```

This produces a simple unconditional increment. But how do I add conditions?

Comment: Can you add the actual expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which output exactly you're expecting, but here's an example of incrementing the counter only at rows which meet the criteria, using [`cum_sum()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.cum_sum.html):

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('code') == 'L').then(pl.lit(1)).otherwise(pl.lit(0)).alias('rrr')
).with_columns(
    pl.col('rrr').cum_sum().over('file') + 1
)

┌───────┬──────┬─────┐
│ file  ┆ code ┆ rrr │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ str  ┆ i32 │
╞═══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ a.txt ┆ X    ┆ 1   │
│ a.txt ┆ Y    ┆ 1   │
│ a.txt ┆ Z    ┆ 1   │
│ a.txt ┆ L    ┆ 2   │
│ b.txt ┆ A    ┆ 1   │
│ b.txt ┆ A    ┆ 1   │
│ c.txt ┆ B    ┆ 1   │
│ c.txt ┆ L    ┆ 2   │
│ c.txt ┆ C    ┆ 2   │
│ c.txt ┆ L    ┆ 3   │
│ c.txt ┆ X    ┆ 3   │
└───────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also `cum_sum` the boolean condition directly:

```py
df.with_columns(
   (pl.col('code') == 'L').cum_sum().over('file').alias('rrr') + 1
)
```

```py
shape: (11, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬─────┐
│ file  ┆ code ┆ rrr │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ str  ┆ u32 │
╞═══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ a.txt ┆ X    ┆ 1   │
│ a.txt ┆ Y    ┆ 1   │
│ a.txt ┆ Z    ┆ 1   │
│ a.txt ┆ L    ┆ 2   │
│ b.txt ┆ A    ┆ 1   │
│ b.txt ┆ A    ┆ 1   │
│ c.txt ┆ B    ┆ 1   │
│ c.txt ┆ L    ┆ 2   │
│ c.txt ┆ C    ┆ 2   │
│ c.txt ┆ L    ┆ 3   │
│ c.txt ┆ X    ┆ 3   │
└───────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: this one is better than my accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that pl.cum_sum() can handle this:

```
(df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('code') == 'L')
                  .then(1)
                  .otherwise(0)
                  .alias('xxx')
                 )
   .with_columns((pl.cum_sum('xxx')+1).over("file").alias('rrr')
                 )
 )
```